# How do I use a sublet a subdomain to another set of nameservers?

Tags: networking, dns

I would like all my servers hosted at Digital Ocean to hold the names `server1.do.example.com`, `server2.do.example.com`.

Say I own `example.com` with DNS hosted at namecheap, which provides me with a pretty good set of options.

Digital Ocean allows me manage my domain using it's own DNS servers, provided I point my domain to it's name servers:

- ns1.digitalocean.com
- ns2.digitalocean.com
- ns3.digitalocean.com

Given my current DNS at Namecheap.com, how do I point `do.example.com` to the three nameservers? so that I can manage `do.example.com` entirely from digital ocean, without having to log into my namecheap.

Essentially, how do I sublet a subdomain to another set of DNS servers

Comment: Change the domains nameservers and all subs will also change.   It's true that it's possible to set distinct nameservers for a sub domain, but if not otherwise  specified a sub domain will have the same nameservers as the main domain.

Comment: @Tyson I would like to keep the root domain with namecheap, this allows the engineers autonomy over the `do` subdomain, while keeping my MX records and other sensitive information secure.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

You need a DNS server that has the ability to set MX records for subdomains. Namecheap.com does not support this, however I found that the Cloudflare DNS does. It's also free, so I just pointed my nameservers to cloudflare and set it up.